# Configure how JAXB unmarshalls boolean

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have some annotated JAXB beans which I am using to unmarshal some XML.

I have several attributes annotated with @XMLAttribute with the type Boolean.

@XmlAttribute
   private Boolean someAttribute;

I would like to customise the umarshalling of **all** boolean attribute so that only exactly the values "true" or "false" are allowed (e.g. "FALse" and not "wibble" would cause the unmarshalling to fail).

I would prefer to avoid having to set an @XmlJavaTypeAdapter on every Boolean attribute if possible. Is there any way to configure how JAXB unmarshals Boolean properties?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a `Schema` expressing your constraints and [attach](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#setSchema%28javax.xml.validation.Schema%29) this to the `Unmarshaller`.

Comment: +1 - For more information on this approach see:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html

Comment: @Blaise Doughan - thanks for the example code, nice blog post

Comment: I was sort-of hoping to generate the schema from the JAXB annotations... have I got things backwards?

Comment: and @flamingpenguin - One thing I just thought of is that the validation approach will allow values of true and false, and also 1 and 0 for nodes of type xsd:boolean:  http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#boolean